# Point spectrum of a positive invertible operator

Tags: gr.group-theory, fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, hilbert-spaces

Let $G$ be a l.c. group and $f$ belong to $C_c(G)$, the space of continuous functions with compact support. Define an operator$T_f$ on $L^2(G)$ by $T_f(g)=f*g$ (the convolution product). If $T_f$ is positive and invertible, could $\|T_f\|$ belong to the point spectrum of $T_f$?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $G$ is abelian.  Presumably the measure being used is Haar measure.  $T_f$ is unitarily equivalent (via the Fourier transform) to multiplication by $\widehat{f}$ on $L^2(\widehat{G})$.  This has norm $\|\widehat{f}\|_\infty$, and that is in the point spectrum if $\{x: \widehat{f}(x) = \|\widehat{f}\|_\infty\}$ has positive measure.  That can happen if $G$ is compact.

EDIT: On the other hand, for $T_f$ to be invertible, you want $\epsilon > 0$ such that $|\widehat{f}(x)| > \epsilon$ almost everywhere.  Since $\widehat{f} \in L^2$, that will require $\widehat{G}$ to be compact.  So we're reduced to the case where $G$ is finite.

Comment: I do not understand the last line of your answer. Does Fourier transform image $C_c(G)$ on $C_c(\hat G)$?

Comment: @MeisamSoleimaniMalekan No, it doesn't, but that is not what Robert is claiming. $\widehat{f}$ is a bounded continuous function on $\widehat{G}$, since $\Vert f \Vert_1 < \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Although the question was already answered by Robert Israel's post, here is a slightly more concrete counterexample:

Let $G$ be the additive group $\mathbb{Z}$ (endowed with the discrete topology). Let $f$ be the function which is $1$ at the point $0$ and $0$ elsewhere. Then $T_f$ is simply the identity operator on $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$. In particular, $1$ is an eigenvalue of $T_f$.

You can easily generalise this example to every discrete group $G$ (be it finite or infinite).

Comment: ... and this is essentially the only example on $\mathbb Z$.  That is, if $f$ has finite support in $\mathbb Z$, $\widehat{f}$ extends to an entire function, so if $\{x \in \mathbb R:\; \widehat{f}(x) = t\}$ has positive measure it must be all of $\mathbb R$, and $T_f$ is a constant multiple of the identity.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Good point! I can't resist, though, to point out the following two things:  (i) The dual group of $\mathbb{Z}$ is the complex unit circle $\mathbb{T}$, so I guess you'd rather consider the set $\{z \in \mathbb{T}: \hat f(z) = t\}$; (ii) The Fourier transform $\hat f$ is a rational function which might have a pole at $0$. (Or did I missunderstand you and you would like to consider the function $\hat f(x) := \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty f(k) e^{ikx}$ rather than $\hat f(z) := \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty f(k)z^k$)?

Comment: I was considering $\widehat{f}(x) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty f(k) e^{ikx}$ which extends from $[0,2\pi)$ to an entire function on $\mathbb C$.  Of course the two points of view are equivalent.